# How to access Google Fit data entered from phone using REST api?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have some activities entered using Google Fit app installed in my phone, and also some activities entered using the website (fit.google.com), and I am using the same google account on both the phone and the website.

The strange things are:

1) I can't see my activities entered by the phone in the website.
2) I can't see my activities entered by the website in my phone.

and more importantly

3) I can't see my activities entered by the phone in the REST api, I can only see those that are entered using the website.

Is there a way to solve this problem and see all the activities using the REST api?

My phone is android 4.0.3 with the latest version of Google Fit and Google play services, it is connected to the internet and the GPS is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, auto-sync was turned off I had to go to Settings-> accounts and sync-> (my google account) and turn on the sync for google fit data and google fit

Comment: you can get activity steps count by Rest API? I mean is it possible to get steps count for "Boxing","Basket ball " etc For All activity? If yes then share API request "oauthplayground"